# By transform scaleX (-1) item goes out of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to flip SVG  tag horizontally by using `transform: scaleX(-1)` it is flipping  But going out of the screen (OR vanishing I am not sure ) even if I am giving the `transform-origin: center;` So whats going on I  searched for it but didn't get the right answer.
Can anyone tell me Why its happening and how to fix it that the svg use tag flip on its own axis?

```css
/* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap'); */

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
*,::before,::after{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;   
}
body{
    font-family:Roboto ;
}
.container{
   width:100%;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    padding:.5em .5em;
}
.header-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:.8em 0em;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
.site-title{
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-weight:400;
    

}
.site-title-span{
    font-weight:750;
    color:#E47700;
}
.nav{
    margin-right:2em;
    width:45%;
}
.nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:black;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:6px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background:#FEBD33;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition: .3s all ease;
}
.active{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color: #FEBD33;
    color: white;
    padding:0 12px;
}
.hero{
    height:40vh;
    font-family: poppins;
    
    
}
.hero-wrapper{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:130px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-shrink: 0; 
    align-items:center;


}
.site-info{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25em;
        line-height: 28px;
        opacity: 0;
     transform: translateY(20px);
     transition:2.5s;
}
.site-info-appear{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);

}

.site-info-heading{
    font-size:3em;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-text{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 6px;
  /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-btn{
    font-size:1.3em;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding:.3em .5em;
    border:none;
    background-color: #33BC00;
    color:white;
    margin-top: 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.hero-beehive{
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;


}
svg{
    border:2px solid red;
     width:155%;
     height:25em;
     float:left;
    position:static;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
 
}
/* HERE IS THE SVG USE TAG CLASS*/
.newCreatedBeeComingFromHive{
    transition: 8s linear;
    transform-origin:center;
    /*You can check by manipulating scaleX to -1 the bee will Vanish*/
    transform: scaleX(1);
}


#small-wing{
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
      
}
#large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-.4deg);

    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(.4deg);

    }
}
.small-wing{
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    transform-origin: center;
      
}
.large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    transform-origin: center;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
    transform-origin: center;


    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(2.5deg);

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <!--header open-->
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div class="site-title">
                    <p>

                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>ee
                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>uzz
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--header closed-->


        <!-- HERO SECTION  -->
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="hero-wrapper">

                <div class="site-info">
                    <h1 class="site-info-heading">
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>ee
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>uzz
                        <span style="font-size:.5em;">TM</span>
                    </h1>
                    <p class="site-info-text">
                        We are providing pure
                        forest bee honey and
                        protecting our environment
                    </p>
                    <button class="site-info-btn">
                        Read more
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="hero-beehive">

                    <svg id="hero-svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 50 630 630" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


                        <symbol id="theBee" viewBox="0 0 78 49" >
                            <g id="complete_bee">
                              <path id="bee head" d="M11.553 35.5047C16.3904 38.8245 21.8681 37.8364 24.0023 36.4532V15.1115C22.9352 14.4397 19.5917 13.499 14.7542 15.1115C9.9168 16.724 8.37329 20.5655 7.99604 21.7512C6.88944 25.2291 6.71554 32.1848 11.553 35.5047Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="bee eye" cx="15.532" cy="21.6908" r="2.96412" fill="#313131" />
                              <path id="bee trunk" d="M65.8034 15.1697C45.3154 7.5816 30.1154 12.008 23.9501 15.1697V36.6299C37.3242 43.649 56.6739 38.0527 64.1435 34.3772C78.0156 27.5513 77.7785 19.6049 65.8034 15.1697Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines" d="M32.961 12.087C30.4711 16.1577 26.9142 26.5519 32.3682 39.3569L35.8065 39.8312C29.8309 27.5004 34.2652 15.5649 36.7551 11.4942L32.961 12.087Z" fill="#4E4E4E" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_2" d="M42.9204 39.8312C36.9447 27.5005 41.2605 15.0907 43.7503 11.02L47.7815 11.1385C45.2917 15.2092 40.5017 27.1448 46.4773 39.4755L42.9204 39.8312Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_3" d="M53.947 38.0527C47.2667 27.313 51.8749 15.6325 54.6584 12.087L58.3339 12.7984C55.5504 16.3439 50.8236 26.246 57.504 36.9856L53.947 38.0527Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_4" d="M63.7528 34.6143C56.6849 26.8661 61.298 16.5925 64.38 14.6955L67.5819 15.8811C65.3292 18.6081 61.4051 23.9435 66.3963 33.1916L63.7528 34.6143Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="small-wing" d="M61.4166 1.06052C55.8203 0.206853 39.1659 8.60919 32.6053 12.0871C54.3264 11.3283 59.9938 9.00435 61.4166 8.05583C63.2303 6.8467 67.0128 1.91419 61.4166 1.06052Z" fill="#99CEFF" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="large-wing" d="M32.9609 11.9685C48.0977 7.26541 80.3166 -2.14073 74.6957 7.34446C68.7675 14.5769 44.3036 13.6679 32.9609 11.9685Z" fill="#81D1FE" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee sting" d="M70.4275 30.7017L73.273 27.7376L76 32.7173L70.4275 30.7017Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="antenna" d="M13.1606 15.8811C13.4768 12.6008 12.1173 5.73197 4.14972 4.4989M10.3151 17.8967C9.36656 14.4583 6.09418 8.05584 0.592773 9.95288" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee legs" d="M30.3525 39.1198L26.2028 43.151L28.2184 46.2337M35.6879 39.9497L31.7753 44.5738L34.2652 48.605" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball" cx="4.38689" cy="4.38033" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball_2" cx="0.592824" cy="9.83431" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <path id="bee behind legs" d="M49.2044 39.2384L45.6475 43.6253L47.6631 45.9965M55.4883 37.8156L50.8643 43.6253L55.4883 46.8265" stroke="black" />
                            </g>
                          </symbol>
                    </svg>

                </div>


               
            


            </div>

        </div>
 
     







           
  <svg>
        <use xlink:href="#theBee" class="newCreatedBeeComingFromHive"
        width="400" height="38.4" x="-30" y="290" />
           
    </svg>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: The svg is 155% of the window width. The "center" around which you scale/flip that svg is at approximately 3/4 of your window width.

Comment: @Thomas can you tell by fixing my code it will help me to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svg width is set to 155%, which means it's 55% wider than the view area, when you flip the image it ends up outside of the view area.

Set your svg width to 100%:

```css
/* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap'); */

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
*,::before,::after{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;   
}
body{
    font-family:Roboto ;
}
.container{
   width:100%;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    padding:.5em .5em;
}
.header-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:.8em 0em;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
.site-title{
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-weight:400;
    

}
.site-title-span{
    font-weight:750;
    color:#E47700;
}
.nav{
    margin-right:2em;
    width:45%;
}
.nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:black;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:6px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background:#FEBD33;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition: .3s all ease;
}
.active{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color: #FEBD33;
    color: white;
    padding:0 12px;
}
.hero{
    height:40vh;
    font-family: poppins;
    
    
}
.hero-wrapper{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:130px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-shrink: 0; 
    align-items:center;


}
.site-info{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25em;
        line-height: 28px;
        opacity: 0;
     transform: translateY(20px);
     transition:2.5s;
}
.site-info-appear{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);

}

.site-info-heading{
    font-size:3em;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-text{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 6px;
  /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-btn{
    font-size:1.3em;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding:.3em .5em;
    border:none;
    background-color: #33BC00;
    color:white;
    margin-top: 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.hero-beehive{
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;


}
svg{
    border:2px solid red;
     width:100%; /* changed */
     height:25em;
     float:left;
    position:static;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
 
}
/* HERE IS THE SVG USE TAG CLASS*/
.newCreatedBeeComingFromHive{
    transition: 8s linear;
    transform-origin:center;
    /*You can check by manipulating scaleX to -1 the bee will Vanish*/
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}


#small-wing{
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
      
}
#large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-.4deg);

    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(.4deg);

    }
}
.small-wing{
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    transform-origin: center;
      
}
.large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    transform-origin: center;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
    transform-origin: center;


    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(2.5deg);

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <!--header open-->
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div class="site-title">
                    <p>

                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>ee
                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>uzz
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--header closed-->


        <!-- HERO SECTION  -->
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="hero-wrapper">

                <div class="site-info">
                    <h1 class="site-info-heading">
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>ee
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>uzz
                        <span style="font-size:.5em;">TM</span>
                    </h1>
                    <p class="site-info-text">
                        We are providing pure
                        forest bee honey and
                        protecting our environment
                    </p>
                    <button class="site-info-btn">
                        Read more
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="hero-beehive">

                    <svg id="hero-svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 50 630 630" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


                        <symbol id="theBee" viewBox="0 0 78 49" >
                            <g id="complete_bee">
                              <path id="bee head" d="M11.553 35.5047C16.3904 38.8245 21.8681 37.8364 24.0023 36.4532V15.1115C22.9352 14.4397 19.5917 13.499 14.7542 15.1115C9.9168 16.724 8.37329 20.5655 7.99604 21.7512C6.88944 25.2291 6.71554 32.1848 11.553 35.5047Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="bee eye" cx="15.532" cy="21.6908" r="2.96412" fill="#313131" />
                              <path id="bee trunk" d="M65.8034 15.1697C45.3154 7.5816 30.1154 12.008 23.9501 15.1697V36.6299C37.3242 43.649 56.6739 38.0527 64.1435 34.3772C78.0156 27.5513 77.7785 19.6049 65.8034 15.1697Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines" d="M32.961 12.087C30.4711 16.1577 26.9142 26.5519 32.3682 39.3569L35.8065 39.8312C29.8309 27.5004 34.2652 15.5649 36.7551 11.4942L32.961 12.087Z" fill="#4E4E4E" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_2" d="M42.9204 39.8312C36.9447 27.5005 41.2605 15.0907 43.7503 11.02L47.7815 11.1385C45.2917 15.2092 40.5017 27.1448 46.4773 39.4755L42.9204 39.8312Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_3" d="M53.947 38.0527C47.2667 27.313 51.8749 15.6325 54.6584 12.087L58.3339 12.7984C55.5504 16.3439 50.8236 26.246 57.504 36.9856L53.947 38.0527Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_4" d="M63.7528 34.6143C56.6849 26.8661 61.298 16.5925 64.38 14.6955L67.5819 15.8811C65.3292 18.6081 61.4051 23.9435 66.3963 33.1916L63.7528 34.6143Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="small-wing" d="M61.4166 1.06052C55.8203 0.206853 39.1659 8.60919 32.6053 12.0871C54.3264 11.3283 59.9938 9.00435 61.4166 8.05583C63.2303 6.8467 67.0128 1.91419 61.4166 1.06052Z" fill="#99CEFF" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="large-wing" d="M32.9609 11.9685C48.0977 7.26541 80.3166 -2.14073 74.6957 7.34446C68.7675 14.5769 44.3036 13.6679 32.9609 11.9685Z" fill="#81D1FE" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee sting" d="M70.4275 30.7017L73.273 27.7376L76 32.7173L70.4275 30.7017Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="antenna" d="M13.1606 15.8811C13.4768 12.6008 12.1173 5.73197 4.14972 4.4989M10.3151 17.8967C9.36656 14.4583 6.09418 8.05584 0.592773 9.95288" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee legs" d="M30.3525 39.1198L26.2028 43.151L28.2184 46.2337M35.6879 39.9497L31.7753 44.5738L34.2652 48.605" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball" cx="4.38689" cy="4.38033" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball_2" cx="0.592824" cy="9.83431" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <path id="bee behind legs" d="M49.2044 39.2384L45.6475 43.6253L47.6631 45.9965M55.4883 37.8156L50.8643 43.6253L55.4883 46.8265" stroke="black" />
                            </g>
                          </symbol>
                    </svg>

                </div>


               
            


            </div>

        </div>
 
     







           
  <svg>
        <use xlink:href="#theBee" class="newCreatedBeeComingFromHive"
        width="400" height="38.4" x="-30" y="290" />
           
    </svg>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer Does use tag is not independent of flipping itself. Because I have a bunch of animations it's a simple part of it and if this question seems helpful you can upvote this